# Set up of ubuntu 18.10 server on ZFS error on boot

Tags: boot, grub2, mount, zfs

I am getting the following error on boot,

```
Command: mount -o zfsutil -t zfs tank/os/ubuntu /root//tank/os/ubuntu
Message: filesystem 'tank/os/ubuntucs' cannot be mounted at 'root//tank/os/ubuntucs' due to canonicalization error 2'
```

It launches into Busybox to fix.
I run:

```
mount -o zfsutil -t zfs tank/os/ubuntu /root
exit
```

and all works fine and system boots properly.

What and where do I need to make a change to make this permanent?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it, had the wrong mountpoint. So in BusyBox ran

```
zfs set mountpoint=/ tank/os/ubuntu
reboot
```

This booted up normally.